# minidlna from one server not being spotted

Tags: networking

I have minidlna set up on two servers on my subnet. One [serverA] is found by the other server [serverB] and the tv. The other [serverB] is not picked up by either other device.
A quick check with both netcat and curl show the other device and port 8200 accessible,
i.e. both:

```
 curl http://10.0.1.112:8200
```

and

```
nc -zv 10.0.1.112 8200
```

are successful. 
Additionally, I have also enabled allmulti and promisc for eth0 on serverb as per [here].[1](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148595)

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by doing two things:

1. Upped the announce rate - changed the notify interval from 900 to 90 in /etc/minidlna.conf, i.e. `notify_interval=90`
2. Added a multicast route.

   route add -net 239.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 eth0

   ifconfig eth0 allmulti multicast

I also tried a few other seemingly legitimate changes to `/etc/minidlna.conf` but they caused things to quit working.

See also: http://www3.pluzzi.com:8083/miniDLNA_on_Ubuntu_8.04

Comment: Thanks! I rebooted the machine after running these commands. It works now. For some reason I have to restart `miniDLNA` occasionally to be seen by clients, but it's still progress.